# why MySQL return null 1000/0

Tags: mysql, sql

Today I use a query 
 `select 1000/0` expected result must be error or exception but mysql return me null , can anyone tell me why . It return this message

Answer (score 1):

This is [well-documented](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-expressions.html) behavior:

> By default, division by zero produces a result of NULL and no warning.
>   By setting the SQL mode appropriately, division by zero can be
>   restricted.
>
> With the `ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO` SQL mode enabled, MySQL handles
>   division by zero differently:
>
> - If strict mode is not enabled, a warning occurs.
> - If strict mode is enabled, inserts and updates involving division by zero are prohibited, and an error occurs.

I would never rely on this behavior (simply because most other databases generate an error).  Use:

```
select 100 / nullif(0, 0)
```

so you explicitly produce a `NULL` value instead of relying on the settings of the database.